# How check token received from Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Let's say that a user logs in using the Microsoft login page and Azure requests application url with token. But how to validate it? Anybody can request application url with fake token. Does Azure API contain url for such a check?

Answer (score 0):

> But how to validate it?

To validate an id_token or an access_token, your app should validate both the token's signature and the claims. To validate access tokens, your app should also validate the issuer, the audience, and the signing tokens. These need to be validated against the values in the OpenID discovery document. For example, the tenant-independent version of the document is located at https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration.

The Azure AD middleware has built-in capabilities for validating access tokens, and you can browse through the [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code) to find one in the language of your choice. For more information on how to explicitly validate a JWT token, see the [manual JWT validation sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation).

For more details, you could refer to [**Validating tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens).